# Update button (sometimes) greyed-out

Tags: wp-update-post

I'd say about 50% of the time when I edit a post the 'update' is greyed out. What I do is copy the mark-up, refresh then re-apply and publish which is a bad work-around because it doesn't address the problem.

Any ideas? I guess I can disable plugins but because the error comes and goes it might take a long time to identify a rogue plugin....

I guess my question is - what would cause this behavior?

Thanks - and Happy NY 2017

Comment: Look in your browser's error console for any javascript errors.

Comment: I faced the same issue when my internet connection is slow. It happened when it tries saving auto-drafts but the internet connection is lost in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Update button is not always active. If the WordPress is auto-saving current post content, the update button will be disabled. This is normally done once every 60 seconds (default autosave interval). Auto-saving is done using AJAX, and if your website is slow to respond, autosave process can take a lot of time to finish.

Depending on the server, this can be from 1 second to 30 or more seconds. And, until autosave completes, the Update button is disabled.

You can change autosave frequency ([WP-Config - Autosave Interval](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Modify_AutoSave_Interval)), or disable it completely. It is not recommended to do so, because if something goes wrong, you may lose your work. Autosave ensures that your content is saved in the database periodically to avoid data loss.